# How can I uninstall or upgrade my old node.js version?

Tags: linux, node.js

some time ago I have installed node.js on my Ubuntu system. with the following steps (dump of my history):

```
309  git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
310  cd node/
311  ./configure 
312  make
313  ls -l
314  node
315  sudo make install
```

My Version is v0.3.2-pre.

Please, is there a clean way to get a new version by uninstall/install or upgrade? I have not much experience with make or git.

Thanks

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Do the exact same thing again. The new binary will be copied over the old one.

- `git clone` creates a copy of git repository node's source code is in
- `cd node/` changes directory to the one you just created with those files
- `./configure` checks for dependencies and creates a makefile
- `make` executes that makefile, which results in compiling the source code into binary executable(s), libraries and any other outputs
- `ls -l` lists the files in the current directory
- `node` runs the `node` binary executable you just compiled from source, to ensure the compilation was successful
- `sudo make install` copies the files you just created from the current directory to their permanent homes, /usr/local/bin and such

The last step overwrites whatever's already there with what you just built.

Comment: But how can I update the sources? It seemed that the repository has moved. So I relocated it with git remote add origin https://github.com/joyent/node.git. If I call "git pull" now I get a message that I have to specify the branch ... git pull <repository> <refspec>.  What do I have to do here?

Comment: Just download the .tgz file off the nodejs.org site, why pull from git at all?

Comment: Oh, please don't sudo node... especially if you are using npm. npm packages *can* have build scripts so if you run npm with sudo, god knows what will happen. You should use `./configure --prefix=~/.local` to make it a local install. Also @Dan when you still have the repo, just pulling the changes will be a lot faster.

Comment: @IvoWetzel: Where do you see `sudo node`?

Comment: trying: git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git 
returns: fatal: destination path 'node' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: @AviramNetanel That seems pretty self-explanatory: don't clone into a non-empty directory. Make a new one. You only need to keep it around long enough to build node, then you can delete the source.

Answer (score 104):

1. Install npm using curl (or wget)
   `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`
2. Install n using npm
   `npm install -g n`
3. Install the latest version of node using n
   `n latest`

[**n**](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) is a node version manager.  It does all the work for you.  It installs and switches to the version you specify, or just switches if you already have it installed.

**Note:** If you're having trouble installing stuff due to permissions, don't use sudo. Enter this command once to set your user account as the owner of the `/usr/local/` directory, so that you can just issue normal commands in there without sudo. It's a more sane alternative.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Comment: hey, i have npm installed. i installed 'n' as well. how do I fire n to update? that command isnt working.

Comment: `n` is sometimes a bit unstable, try `nvm`

Comment: I guess nvm is not quite stable either. I was trying to install it. But it's not working and then I tried to uninstall it with `npm uninstall nvm`. But the uninstall script ruined my .bashrc file. The problem is with nvm 0.0.6 and Ubuntu 11.04 at the time of writing. If you wanna try it, you'd better backup your .bashrc file.

Comment: use it like this 
   `sudo n latest`

Comment: @iUsable I had the same problem and it was the package `n` wasn't global, if you do `sudo npm install -g n` then you can do `sudo n 0.6.12` or like @Maysam says. Cheers!

Comment: Worked for me. I only had to remove/purge the existing nodejs package first.

Answer (score 18):

## *1 Minute Solution Without* using `sudo`:

The current stable "LTS" version of node is **12.18.4** (***2020-10-03***) *see*: [***nodejs.org***](https://nodejs.org) for *latest*.

### Step 1 - *Get [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)* (Node Version Manger)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

> If you're *curious* about the installation command *read* the [source code](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/nvm.sh)
> ... its been *reviewed* by *several* [node.js security experts](https://snyk.io)

### Step 2 - *Install* the version of node.js you need

Once you've got **NVM** you can install a *specific* version of Node.js using the nvm command:

```sh
nvm install v12.18.4
```

**Note**: you may need to close & re-open your terminal window for `nvm` command to be available.

You should expect to see something like this in your terminal:

```
Now using node v12.18.4
```

### Step 3 - *Enjoy* the rest of your day!

*Yes*, it's *that easy* and didn't require `sudo`!
Now ***please Upvote*** this (*so others can avoid `sudo`-installing things!*)
and have a *lovely day* writing node.js code!

> *Microsoft **Windows** User*? *Use*: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

### tl;dr

Review of the node mailing list indicates that using **NVM** (*Node Version Manager*) is the *preferred* way to manage your nodejs versioning/upgrading. see: [github.com/nvm-sh/nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

**NVM** is considered "*better*" than **N** because the *verbose* commands mean is *much* easier to keep track of what you are doing in your Terminal/SSH Log. Its also *faster*, ***saves kittens*** by ***not requiring*** [**`sudo`**](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3) and is used by the team at [**NPM**](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/security) the node.js ***security experts***!

Answer (score 10):

This worked well for me on Ubuntu 12.04:
http://dev.squarecows.com/2012/06/28/nodejs-0-8-on-ubuntu-12-04/

```
add-apt-repository ppa:richarvey/nodejs
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs npm
```

No need to build anything. This will be done via the package manager.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest Node version manager **for Windows** is [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist).

1. Make sure you've uninstalled node - be sure the node folder's deleted (defaults to Program Files) and it's removed from your user and system path. Also delete the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders from `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming`.
2. `git clone git://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist.git` or use the supplied .zip file if you haven't got / have no luck with git.
3. Add `.../nodist/bin` to your path
4. `nodist update` to install dependencies
5. `nodist latest` or `nodist add 0.10.10 && nodist 0.10.10` to install and use the latest version. `nodist stable`, in turn, gives you the latest stable build.
6. `node` should enter you in interactive mode ( a `>` before the prompt)
7. If it worked, victory lap: `> console.log('YYYYYYYYYYES!')`

There's also [nmvw](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw) which requires Python 2.7 and git; I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to update to latest stable is using the NPM. 
Just execute the following:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

If you want latest possible just replace the last command with

```
sudo n latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, there is Node.js official documentation [over here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). 
I've tried to explain simply for variety cases for Ubuntu OS the below.

1. Remove the current old version of Node.js by using the following code;

   a.  If Node.js **was installed by using source code** with `./configure` and `make install` commands;

   1. If the installation directory still exists;

      - Enter into the node.js directory using `cd` command like `cd node-v0.12.3/`
      - Run the command of `sudo make uninstall`
   2. If the installation directory has been deleted a while ago;

      - Download the source code again by using `wget` command like this
         `wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.3/node-v0.12.3.tar.gz`
         
        If you don't know the current version `node -v` command might be used for this. In my case version is v0.12.3
      - Extract the tar file using `tar -xvf node-v0.12.3.tar.gz`
      - Enter into the new directory using `cd node-v0.12.3`
      - Preparing package for the remove operation using `./configure` command
      - Finally remove the installed package properly using `sudo make uninstall` command

   b. If Node.js **was installed by using `apt-get` command**, `sudo apt-get remove nodejs` command can be used to remove the current Node.js package.
2. Install the latest version of Node.js by using as directed by the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) with the following commands;

   `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -`
   [For now setup_5.x is the newest version]
   `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

And finally let's check the installation using `nodejs -v`.

Answer (score 0):

sudo n latest/stable would not work now, as the latest is 0.8.1 which links to node-v0.8.1-RC1.tar.gz and n will look for node-v0.8.1.tar.gz, can do sudo n 0.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy. Just Install "node version manager" using command :

**npm install -g n**.

Then enter command:

**n latest**

I am assuming you have npm installed over node package. This will upgrade your node to latest version.

Comment: You posted the same answer but with less explanation as someone posted 3 years earlier? why?