# npm install error: TypeError: uid must be an int

Tags: node.js, npm, typeerror

After upgrade my Node.js, It seems sth wrong. It cannot install any package with "-g". Here is the pic link of the error snap http://photo.weibo.com/1495160301/wbphotos/large/mid/3603537491210131/pid/591e55edjw1e6xpnw75h1j20wt0lydjm. (OS X 10.8.4）

Comment: There is a value in your bash_profile that might need to be changed. I did a bunch of crazy thing with my profile and broke all global modules for a while. export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue when i tried to install phonegap with -g option.
i solved the issue installing the newest version of Node

Comment: This helped me upgrade to the newester version:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570971/2044993