# Cannot upgrade Node version with the common commands

Tags: node.js

I have trouble upgrading Node.js.

Currently, I have `node --version` "v0.8.18" and I would like to upgrade to the latest "v0.10.20". So I followed [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) that does not include NVM, since I want to know how to do it from scratch.  However, after trying, I still get `node --version` "v0.8.18".

I am on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine, on my home directory.

Specifically I did:

Try 1:

```
alice@simba:~$ node --version
v0.8.18

alice@simba:~$ sudo n stable
sudo: n: command not found

alice@simba:~$ sudo npm install n -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n/-/n-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/n/-/n-1.1.0.tgz
/usr/bin/n -> /usr/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
n@1.1.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/n

alice@simba:~$ sudo n stable
     install : 0.10.20
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/0.10.20
       fetch : http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.20/node-v0.10.20-linux-x64.tar.gz
        ...
        ...#############/usr/bin/node
       installed : v0.10.20

alice@simba:~$ node --version
v0.8.18
```

Try again:

```
alice@simba:~$ npm cache clean -f

alice@simba:~$ sudo npm install n -g
/usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
n@1.1.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n

alice@simba:~$ n stable
/usr/local/bin/node

alice@simba:~$ sudo n stable
/usr/local/bin/node

alice@simba:~$ node --version
v0.8.18
```

Comment: I use nvm myself, but something I've bumped up against in the past is that installing a version and selecting a version are different operations. It may be that your new version is installed but not currently the default. Try `n use 0.10.20`

Comment: @Richard_Marr, that command worked! Thank you so much! Please put it as an answer and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `nvm` myself, but something I've bumped up against in the past is that installing a version and selecting a version as active are different operations.

It may be that your new version is installed but not currently the default. Try:

```
n use 0.10.20
```