# Error Installing Yeoman on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yeoman

When i try to install Yeoman on ubuntu i am getting the following error.

[image]

```
harsha@harshamv:~$ sudo npm install yo -g
[sudo] password for harsha: 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sudo-block
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/open/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/open/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sudo-block
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://github.com/Filirom1/nopt/tarball/master#pull-request-in-progress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/download
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/class-extend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isbinaryfile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dargs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/download
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/file-utils
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/class-extend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/through2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 200 https://github.com/Filirom1/nopt/tarball/master#pull-request-in-progress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/through
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/each-async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tempfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es5-ext
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/memoizee
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tempfile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSselect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm WARN package.json punycode@1.2.3 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/event-emitter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/next-tick
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/CSSwhat
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js

> yo@1.1.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! yo@1.1.2 postinstall: `node ./scripts/doctor`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node ./scripts/doctor"` failed with 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./scripts/doctor
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "yo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/harsha
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/harsha/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**EDIT**

After Trying MortezaLSC's solution -- i am getting the following error

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js

> yo@1.1.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! yo@1.1.2 postinstall: `node ./scripts/doctor`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node ./scripts/doctor"` failed with 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./scripts/doctor
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/share
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/share/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter nor did I nominate for closing, but a wall of errors with no demonstration of background investigation or reading comprehension is not very respectful towards the people from whom you are expecting help with your problem.

Comment: @tripleee i am trying to install. thats like the STEP 0. and i am facing the problem. i dont even understand how to make it work. tried to google and search on SO as well

Answer (score 10):

I ran into various problems like this on both Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOS 6.  I was running the latest version of npm on both, but no luck - lots of errors.

After much Googling, apt-getting and yumming it finally hit me to upgrade node itself.  See this [answer on upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version), i.e.:

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

After that I went back to:

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

and it installed just fine on both OSes!

Well, on CentOS I did also have to go to my home directory and do:

```
sudo chmod -R myusername .npm
```

(.npm and everything under it was owned by root, causing trouble when running yo generators).

Comment: Worked for me as well. I would mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Answer (score 3):

the solution is [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager)

you should install nodejs-legacy or using the *reg3n* option

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Here's the full article:
http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/

Would someone enlight us on the details about this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Found this topic today, decided to post solution that worked for me.

So the problem is with the location of your globally installed packages. The installer can't access the folders, and throws up an error.

So what you do, is you tell npm to put your packages in a folder inside your /home directory (or wherever you want), that can be accessed without `sudo`.

[Here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)'s a guide on how to do that. Go check it out, it's kinda long to copy-paste.

And [here](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo) is a script that does it automatically  (it prompts for the folder location).

I pasted the original guides locations since I realise my explanations can be a bit lacking (I am a ubuntu and Angular beginner).

Hope it helps