# React-native init error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to install React-native to my ubuntu 14.04. I have sucessfully installed `react-native-cli`, but when I'm trying to run `react-native init reactApp` trene is an error:

```
pavlov@pavlov-System-Product-Name:~$ node -v
v0.12.7
pavlov@pavlov-System-Product-Name:~$ react-native init reactApp
prompt: Directory reactApp already exist. Continue?:  (no) y
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /home/pavlov/reactApp
Installing react-native package from npm...
You are currently running Node v0.12.7 but React Native requires >=4. Please use a supported version of Node.
See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
/home/pavlov/reactApp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:56
  const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/pavlov/reactApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:214:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pavlov/reactApp/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading node? React Native requires >=4

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to install Node 4.0 or higher. Actually it even says it in your console output.

Here is how i installed Node on my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Good luck!

Comment: it throws an error W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download the latest version, in this case v4.4.3.