# Upgrading NodeJS on SemaphoreCI

Tags: node.js, semaphore-ci

I'm using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and running the project through [SemaphoreCI](http://semaphoreci.com). 
The project works fine on my machine but fails on Semaphore. I suspect that it is because of node version difference (mine is v5.5, Semaphore is using v0.12).

Google gave me [so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions) on how to upgrade my node, but almost all of these need `sudo` access. I was wondering if anyone had similar issues on Semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semaphore gives you full sudo access, so you can run any linux command as you do in your dev environment, here is example from [the Semaphore docs](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/how-to-install-dependency.html).

Full list of preinstalled versions of NodeJS on Semaphore you can [find here](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/languages/javascript/javascript-support-on-semaphore.html). As you can see, there is no `5.5` version on the platform so you need to install and switch to it with following commands as part of your build:

```
nvm install 5.5
nvm use 5.5
```

If you want to use some version that is already preinstalled you can do that with following command:

```
nvm use 5.6
```