# SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier when using discord-webhooks / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks, discord

I am attempting to create a simple javascript to serve as a webhook for Discord.  I have removed the URL.

```
const DiscordWebhook = require("discord-webhooks");
let myWebhook = new DiscordWebhook("removedtopostonstackexchange")
myWebhook.on("ready", () => {
myWebhook.execute({
content:"Hello from a webhook",
username:"Mr Webhook",
avatar_url:"https://example.com/image.png"});});
myWebhook.on("error", (error) => {console.warn(error);});
```

When I run this in runkit it works fine and a successful push is sent to the Discord channel, however, uploading to my linux server returns the following error:

```
[root@pikachu crash-watcher]# node test.js

/servers/crash-watcher/test.js:2
let myWebhook = new DiscordWebhook("removedtopostonstackexchange
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
[root@pikachu crash-watcher]#
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your NodeJS version via `node --version`, it's probably out of date

Support for the `let` statement should be added in NodeJS 4

---

To upgrade your NodeJS version, run:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

*Sidenote: For windows user, [check out this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25598244/3437046)*

Answer (score 0):

The nodejs version installed on the server did not like using let.