# how to update Node to Node v4.2.6 ? - Node 6 LTS version

Tags: node.js, version

how to I can update Node js to Node v4.2.6 - Node LTS version from terminal of linux?

i have this error in terminal ubuntu:

```
ERR: Your Node.js version is v4.2.6. Please update to the latest Node 6 LTS version (or latest Node).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is of course a duplicate question but... You should use `n` to achieve node version in an easier way:

- https://github.com/tj/n to read instructions.
- But is easy as follow:

  `$ sudo npm i -g n`
- Then install a node version as follow:

  `$ sudo n 8.1.3`
- Or simply:

  `$ sudo n latest`