# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16) in elasticdump

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I was trying to move elasticsearch data from one server to another using elasticdump. When I giving

```
elasticdump --input=http://192.168.0.122:9200/my_index --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index --type=mapping
```

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/lib/transports/elasticsearch.js:668
>   var { awsChain, awsAccessKeyId, awsIniFileProfile } =
>   self.parent.options
>           ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at getIo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/lib/ioHelper.js:29:18)
>       at new elasticdump (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/elasticdump.js:43:3)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump:96:16)

How should I solve this error?

Comment: I suspect that you don't have a recent version of node.js installed locally, i.e. one that doesn't support ES6 and later. You should make sure that [at least node.js v8+](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md) is installed.

Comment: hi Val, actually I am using ES 2.4.4

Comment: I'm talking about node.js, i.e. the runtime that elasticdump runs on. Your issue has nothing to do with ES itself. Run `node -v` and tell us what you get

Comment: Ok val, Thank You

Comment: I have checked the version, its v4.2.6

Comment: There you go, you need to [upgrade your local node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) and once done, you should be better off

Comment: ok Val, let me check it

Comment: hi Val, I have updated node js to the latest version. got the message installed : v10.0.0, but it still showing v4.2.6 while checking the version

Comment: Thank you Val, Now its working fine. :)

Comment: how did you install? did you switch to the new version after installing?

Comment: yes, I just followed the steps in the link that u shared

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your version of Node.js is too old and doesn't support  the latest features.

elasticdump requires [at least node.js v8+](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md), so you should [upgrade node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) and then it should work.