# Hyperledger Fabric Fabcar node enrollAdmin.js

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to run  fabcar sample. But at the step of run a command which is `node enrollAdmin.js` an error occurs like below;

```
/home/<username>/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:742
    async _createOrUpdateChannel(request, have_envelope) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<username>/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/index.js:25:18)
```

I have checked the file which is error occurred. I find line 742 but I couldn't see syntax error.

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue, did you get the solution?

Comment: Please see the latest answer on the post.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, it works after i updated to Node v8.9.4.

npm rebuild and run

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the Hyperleder fabric Pre-Requisites that the only node version 8.9.X is supported. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/prereqs.html 
[image: Fabric-Pre Requisites]

Would advise you to upgrade the node version. Use this link to upgrade the node version: [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version)