# Javascript - flatMap method over array - (flatMap is not a function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, flatmap

According to the Mozilla Developer Website:

`The flatMap() method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map followed by a flat of depth 1, but flatMap is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.`

Example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];

const flatMap = arr.flatMap(x => x);
console.log(flatMap);
```

`TypeError: arr.flatMap() is not a function`

Why is this returning this error?

**EDIT**

I am running this through Atom text editor and have used HomeBrew to update it to the latest version using `brew upgrade node` and it is still giving me the same error.

I have also tried `npm install n -g`

Comment: It' probably not supported in your browser yet. But, what's the point of using `flatMap` on that array?

Comment: I just want to see that it works and then test other values as well.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) has a lot of examples and [alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative) if it's not supported in your browser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative

Comment: It's just a problem of [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) as it's only supported on new browsers.

Answer (score 29):

I was getting this when testing with jest, it's because `flatmap` is only [part of node 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) and I was using node 10.

As a workaround, I added `require('core-js/stable');` in my `setupTests.ts`.

I presume also there are some browsers that won't have this either. As such I will also put that require line in my application imports somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `flatMap` is not supported on your browser.
Here you are a complete list of supported browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=flatMap

If you really want to use it, here you are a polyfill that will grant support down to ES3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.flatmap

By the way, it is useful when applied on a multidimensional array!

Comment: Appreciate it, I'm running it on atom and believe I updated it the latest version of node, Still doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest to use when developing on node: https://github.com/creationix/nvm :)

Answer (score 2):

It means you're using a web browser or other development environment that does not support [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (currently Edge and IE have no support). CanIUse table [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap).

Also note that it is used primarily for multidimensional arrays (to avoid chaining `map` and `flat`, hence `flatMap`).

Comment: I would just upgrade by using homebrew in my case right? `brew upgrade node` right?

Comment: Even easier (don't need Homebrew) - `npm install n -g` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076029/10221765)).

Comment: Just uninstall node and reinstall it using nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm