# TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I created a React app and then integrated Tailwind to it. When I ran `npm start`, I got this error.

```
TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function[![enter image description here][1]][1]
TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function
    at flattenColorPalette (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette.js:8:83)
    at /media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/plugins/divideColor.js:27:53
    at plugins.forEach.plugin (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/processPlugins.js:69:5)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _default (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/processPlugins.js:63:11)
    at /media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:60:54
    at LazyResult.run (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:288:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:212:26)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:225:14)
    at /media/rishi/142468BD2468A408/web/tailwind-react-demo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:254:14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tailwind-react-demo@0.1.0 watch:css: `postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tailwind-react-demo@0.1.0 watch:css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rishi/.npm/_logs/2020-11-19T08_16_39_825Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tailwind-react-demo@0.1.0 start: `npm run watch:css && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tailwind-react-demo@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rishi/.npm/_logs/2020-11-19T08_16_39_906Z-debug.log
```

[image]

This is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/tailwind-react-demo.

Comment: Please include error messages (and stacktrace) as plain, formatted text instead of as an image, text is searchable. Please also include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of all relevant code to the issue.

Comment: This is a error message TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function. Github repo: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/tailwind-react-demo

Comment: Maybe you target an older ES version which `flatMap` not supported in.

Comment: how do I fix that? I have already attached code github repo.

Comment: I just noticed that it's not in the code you wrote but in your modules. Anyway, I just cloned your repo and run it and no error comes out and the app running as expected.

Comment: Links out to external resources are ok as *supplemental material*, but you should include the relevant code here in your question so it stays with the question here in SO, links tend to decay over time. Also, make it easier for people to spend their free time to help you. We shouldn't have to dig through your repo to suss out the relevant details.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't why I am getting this error that's why I don't include the exact code

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know why it's showing on my laptop'

Comment: What's your node version? Might related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123483/863110.

Comment: @MoshFeu node version: v10.19.0

Comment: The stacktrace tells you where the error occurs. It looks to be an issue with something you've installed for tailwind. Have you tried a git clean (or other methods of clearing the node modules) and rerunning `npm install`? Seems likely an issue on your machine if Mosh was able to clone and run it.

Comment: I upgraded my node version from 10.19.0 to v14.15.1. It solved my issue. Thanks @MoshFeu Drew Reese

Comment: I have some doubts like If I want to extend the color palette I need to create tailwind.config.js file and then extend the color palette. Another doubt is I have to install postcss and postcss-cli both in order to work with a tailwind?

Comment: This is a different question :) I'm not that familiar with tailwind but A. Seems so: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#colors. B. You have them already in your package.json

Comment: BTW seems like all of the [following packages](https://github.com/rishipurwar1/tailwind-react-demo/blob/210fd03fc09eeddb268248e1271254904e86861d/package.json#L6-L11) should be under `devDependencies`.

Comment: You mean     "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.0",  these packages should be under devDependencies but not tailwindcss package

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I had the same issue today and solved it by updating Node.js to the latest version.

`flatMap` was introduced with Node.js v11. You are probably using an older version. You can check it by running: `node -v`.

I suggest managing node versions using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

Very simple to install with cURL:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash`

Then restart your terminal, and to install the latest Node.js version just run `nvm install node`.

To check if the Node.js version you are using has changed, you can run `node -v` again.

Comment: Note that you have to **rm -rf node_modules** and then do an **npm install** again if your server's node version changes

Comment: It worked for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: instead of restarting your terminal, you can just source your bashrc file like this: `... && source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: To have nvm available globally, modify | bash with | sudo bash