# Why is not bulkDelete working in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bulk-delete

I tried to make a bulk delete command to my discord bot, but it doesn't work.

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

if(args[1] == 'bulkdelete') {
  const deleteCount = parseInt(args[2], 10);
  message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteCount || 100)
    .then(() => message.reply('Removing messages'))
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

When I try to use it, it returns an error.
`TypeError: Object.entries(...).filter(...).flatMap is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We would need some more debugging information, perhaps the error has more information like the line number and file in which the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what part of the code is specifically causing the error `TypeError: Object.entries(...).filter(...).flatMap is not a function`, but given that this error is occurring, I may know a fix.

`Object.entries()` returns an array, `array.filter()` returns an array, and arrays in [node.js v11+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) have the function property `flatMap()`. Since the error is telling you that the `flatMap()` property is not a function on an array, you're probably using an older version of nodeJS.

To fix this, you need to update to node 11 or a newer version.

Relevant resources:
[Javascript - flatMap method over array - (flatMap is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530690/javascript-flatmap-method-over-array-flatmap-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thank you. I updated node.js and it works just fine.