# Trying to install NodeJS on older mac

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, homebrew

I'm using homebrew to install a few REPLs. I already succeeded with Ruby/irb, but now, when I try to install the javascript REPL with `brew install node` I get an error message. Then when I try to run `node` in terminal, I get the `-bash: node: command not found`.

I've tried searching for the relevant versions of nodejs for High Sierra, hoping I'd find which version worked with that specific OS, but no luck. I did find that I can input `brew search node` to get a list of available node versions, but I still don't know which one, and I don't want to make a serious mistake and fudge my system. Does anyone have a solution/suggestion?

Comment: please provide error message you get when trying to install node.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280757/how-to-upgrade-node-to-specific-version-in-macos-mojave-and-update-the-active-p/58281348#58281348