# Why n throws error? Error: sudo required (or change ownership, or define N_PREFIX)

Tags: node.js

I want to install latest Node.js version

```
n latest

  installing : node-v14.2.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/14.2.0
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied

  Error: sudo required (or change ownership, or define N_PREFIX)
```

Something is wrong with ownership. I tried to fix this

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n
```

Same error again.

```
n latest
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/node': Permission denied
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/npm': Permission denied
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/npx': Permission denied
```

Permissions in n

```
/usr/local/n$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 miki root 4096 мај  8 13:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 мај  8 13:29 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 miki miki 4096 мај  8 13:29 versions/
```

SOLVED

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
```

Comment: You tried change owner for `~/.npm`, but it says that it can not create directory in `/usr/local/n`.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Well, obviously, change the owner for `usr/local/n`... `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n`

Comment: [Never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version/42690662#42690662) [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js/19584407#19584407) `sudo n latest`! It will mess with permissions and break udpates for the rest of your global npm packages. `/usr/local/n` is a bad choice from a user perspective. Use a [3rd-party installer](https://github.com/tj/n#third-party-installers) to get a working setup out of the box.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

### Context

`n` command downloads and installs to `/usr/local` by default, creating the `/usr/local/n` folder with these permissions by default:

```
drwxr-xr-x root  wheel  .
drwxr-xr-x root  wheel  ..
drwxr-xr-x root  wheel  versions
```

### Possible solutions

#### A. Add yourself to the group and grant write permission (safer):

1. Add yourself to the `wheel` group.

   1.1 macOS:

   ```
    sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a $(whoami) -t user wheel
   ```

   1.2 GNU/Linux:

   ```
    sudo usermod -a -G wheel $(whoami)
   ```
2. Allow `wheel` members writing permission on that folder:

   ```
    sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/n/
   ```

#### B. Change ownership directly to your user (quicker):

You would need to change where `n` stores `node` versions ownership:

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n && sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n/
```

#### C. Change the folder where `n` saves node binaries, etc.

> The n command downloads and installs to /usr/local by default, but you may override this location by defining N_PREFIX.
>
> Source: https://github.com/tj/n#optional-environment-variables

1. Create a folder, ie: `$HOME/.n`

   ```
    mkdir $HOME/.n
   ```
2. Define the environment variable `N_PREFIX` adding to your shell initialisation file this line:

   2.1. bash *(~/.bashrc)* or zsh *(~/.zshrc)*:

   ```
    export N_PREFIX=$HOME/.n
   ```

   2.2. fish *(~/.config/fish/config.fish)*:

   ```
    set -x N_PREFIX $HOME/.n
   ```
3. Add the new binary path to your environment's `$PATH`:

   3.1. bash/zsh:

   ```
    export PATH=$N_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
   ```

   3.2. fish:

   ```
    set -x PATH $N_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
   ```

Comment: No such file or directory.

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n && sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n`

Comment: Plan A doesn't work in my macOS.

Comment: @zhuziyi Which command is not working? Which version of macOS?

Comment: @IgnacioLago My macOS version is Sonoma 14.1 (23B74).

After executing the commands listed in Plan A above, the problem was not resolved.

Comment: @zhuziyi OK, I will try to break my installation and fix it again using that version. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

you just need to define the N_PREFIX.

- First create the folder where the n data will be saved

  `mkdir $HOME/.n`
- then export the N_PREFIX in your .bashrc file

  `export N_PREFIX=$HOME/.n`

if you use fishshell, add this to your .config.fish file: `set -x N_PREFIX $HOME/.n`

Comment: Don't forget to add $HOME/.h to your path

Comment: On macOS Monterey I also had to add `~/.n/bin` to my `$PATH` variable in the `~/.zprofile` file:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.n/bin`

Answer (score 8):

A preferred solution should be to override the default location to a directory that doesn't require admin privileges, by defining `N_PREFIX`.

For updating the directory to your user directory, use the following:

```
export N_PREFIX=$HOME/.n
export PATH=$N_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
```

Doc ref: https://github.com/tj/n#optional-environment-variables

Comment: this will only work for one terminal session

Comment: @darrenz not if you add those environment variables to your PATH

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs the proper way without using sudo.
Update existing proper installation:

```
npm i -g n
N_PREFIX=$HOME/.local n stable
```

Reference: https://guillermo.at/update-node-proper-way

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, in fact, the current user does not have permissions to the global directory.

Trying to use the solution in Ignacio Lago's answer didn't work, and in the end it was solved perfectly with the following method:

1. First install node with brew, and install n globally.

```
brew install node
npm install -g n
```

2. Execute the diagnostic command for n

```
n doctor
```

It will list what the problem is, just refer to the help suggestion in the error list.

Finally, remember to uninstall the node installed with brew, and it will be solved perfectly.

```
brew uninstall node
```

Perfect！