# App created with create-react-app fails to compile (kleur' do not define a valid './colors' target)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After creating a new react project `npx create-react-app` and then starting the app, I get the following error:

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6- 
oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src?? 
postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Package exports for'/Users/borisgrunwald/Desktop/programmering/Javascript/tutorials/React/Fireship/StripeAppFrontend/stripe/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/kleur' do not define a valid './colors' target
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481678/react-app-failed-to-compile-after-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install latest version of autoprefixer through this command
**

> npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0

**

Answer (score 0):

./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css) Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\myapp\node_modules\colorette'

Try this

npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0

Thank you..

Comment: Why "try"? Is this a risky experiment the outcome of which you cannot predict?