# Can't install typeorm with Yarn (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: yarnpkg

[image: ERROR]

This error is appearing when I try to install TypeORM dependency.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Node 10 is out of support, you should already have upgraded.

Comment: Thank you, i will do that!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to upgrade *node* on your machine? If you don't have other project dependencies that are bound to your current version (10)?

You can check how to do it at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076029/2622455

The version 12 would be otherwise enough for your need:

```
n 12
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try to do this!