# How to upgrade Node.js on a mac?

Tags: node.js

I am running into an issue I won't get into that has potential solutions involving upgrading Node. Easy enough right? No, not at all. I have tried running the latest Node installer for Mac. I have tried upgrading with nvm. I have tried upgrading with `n`. No matter what I do my `node -v` doesn't change. I have tried all of the top posts' solutions related to this seemingly simple process. It did actually show a newer version number of Node after attempting to upgrade with `nvm` however after closing and opening the terminal it now shows the node version I began with.

I suspect that I now have multiple installations of Node on my computer which just introduces a host of new problems. However, how the heck do I upgrade Node JS properly once and for all? Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: you run `nvm use 16.8`  after installing the version you want I guess?

Comment: what `n stable` resulted?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) answer; if it does not suffice then just delete / remove node.js entirely from your pc and download it again.

Answer (score 1):

> Updated

Maybe just uninstall node and delete all node-related files. If you have installed node using homebrew then it is pretty straightforward, just run these commands:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node 
brew uninstall --force node
```

Then update and install nvm

```
brew update
brew install nvm
```

Next, create a directory for NVM in home.

```
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Now, configure the required environment variables. Edit the following configuration file in your home directory

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

and, add below lines to ~/.bash_profile ( or ~/.zshrc for macOS Catalina or later).

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Press `ESC + :wq` to save and close your file.

Next, load the variable to the current shell environment. From the next login, it will automatically loaded.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

> Old

Install your desired node version using the command

```
nvm install <version>
```

Then you can see all the installed versions using the command:

```
nvm list
```

Then use can switch to specific version using command:

```
nvm use <version>
```

Another method is to uninstall and delete all the node related files and install using `Homebrew`, but I recommend and use `nvm`

```
brew install node@<version>
```

Comment: `nvm use` doesn't seem to be permanent and `nvm alias default myVersion` doesn't seem to actually affect `node -v`...

Comment: Have you added nvm to your environment variable? I have edited my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/*
```

then:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
brew unlink node
brew link node
```

if doesn't work de link you can use this:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

Anyway, after first command you can update brew or uninstall and install again node and do the link if it's necessary without problem...