# TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to code a bot with the new discord.js version but when I try to log in, it's prompting me this error

```
/home/max/Schreibtisch/Discord Bots/Perplex/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:279
    if (!Object.hasOwn(given, key) || given[key] === undefined) {
                ^

TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function
    at mergeDefault (/home/max/Schreibtisch/Discord Bots/Perplex/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:279:17)
    at new BaseClient (/home/max/Schreibtisch/Discord Bots/Perplex/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:25:20)
    at new Client (/home/max/Schreibtisch/Discord Bots/Perplex/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:43:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/max/Schreibtisch/Discord Bots/Perplex/src/bot.js:26:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

this is my bot code

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 20):

I don't think there is an error in this code snippet. If this is your `src/bot.js` file then it seems okay.

However, the error says *"Object.hasOwn is not a function"* and [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is only available since node.js v16.9.0.

Discord.js v14 requires node.js 16.9 or higher, so make sure you're up to date. To check your node version, use `node -v` in your terminal or command prompt, and if it's older than this, [update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version)!

For more breaking changes, you can check out this answer: [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/6126373)