# Question Mark after variable name

Tags: javascript

I got this error when I used question mark after variable in react js

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:28) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> ```
> |   console.log(cryptos);
> |   useEffect(function () {
> >     var filteredData = data?.data.coins.filter(function (item) {
> |       return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);      
> |     });
> ```

Anyone faced this error before?

Comment: that syntax is fairly recent, if you're using an old parser it will be confused

Answer (score 1):

Just check your NodeJS version with the following command.

```bash
node --version
```

As mentioned in the browser compatibility in the [Optional chaining documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility), the NodeJS version should be at least **14.0.0**.

If your NodeJS version is lower than it, you should [upgrade it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) to use these latest features.

Answer (score 0):

?. is an operator named as optional chain operator. It is new in es11. May be it's not updated in react.js , that's why you are getting error